# Magento save many to many models

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I have created a custom module with 3 models (student, room, studentroom).
The studentroom is used to store the relation between student & room (manytomany).
I have maked the form + grid to the students and rooms and i can create both of them. i want now to add a multiselect in the student form to select the rooms (until now its ok). When i save or edit my student how can i save or display also the association in studentroom.
Anyone has an idea ? A module with the same functionalities ?

Thx for advance

Answer (score 1):

Magento's ORM has no built-in methods for the sort of one to many and many to many relationships you're describing above.  As such, it's up to each individual developer to implement their own `save` methods that (before or after calling `parent::save()`) handle any extra relationships an object might have.